# Wordpress image links 404

Tags: wordpress, image, database-migration

Im migrating a wordpress site for the first time. I can get the site to load here: http://www.foureyescomic.com/ by updating the config file and the database table like this:

[image: siteurl and home options]

But now I'm getting images with broken links like this:
[image: urls of broken links]

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `wp_posts` table in database. [Here](https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-change-the-url-of-a-wordpress-site-6098) is a workaround.

If you the original address is up yet, it is more convenient to use a `plugin` for migration. [Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that happens because the absolute URLs of the images are stored as text within your posts' content in the **wp_posts** table. If your site's backend is functioning, you can use a database find/replace plugin to find the old urls in that table and replace them with the new urls. Or you can just do it with SQL/phpMyadmin if you're comfortable with that.

I find the easiest is by using this plugin: [Better Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/)

It's pretty straightforward from there:

- Install and activate the plugin, then in wp-admin go to **Tools** > **Better Search Replace**.
- In the **Search For** field, put your old url. Ex:  http://www.oldurl.com
- Then in **Replace With** put your new url. Ex:  http://www.newurl.com
- In the **Select tables** section select **wp_posts** (or whatever your posts table is if you use a differnet prefix)
- You can leave **Run as dry run?** checked if you want to do a dry run first to see what'll be changed. If it's unchecked, the changes will be made in your database.
- Hit the **Search/Replace** button and that should do it!

Make sure you're using the exact strings you want to find and replace, and think about whether the search string could potentially occur anywhere else in that table where you wouldn't want it to change, otherwise you could screw things up. You should definitely have your DB backed up before you run this.

Hope that helps.